# Error unix_socket_directory in upgrading from postgresql 9.2 to 9.6 in RedHat

Tags: database, postgresql, centos, redhat

I'am strugling for hours already in upgrading my postgresql server 9.2 to 9.6.
Here is what I've done:

Ran this as postgres:

```
/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_upgrade --old-bindir=/usr/bin/ --new-bindir=/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/ --old-datadir=/var/lib/pgsql/data/ --new-datadir=/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/ --check
```

Got the output:

```
Performing Consistency Checks on Old Live Server
-------------------------------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok
Checking database user is the install user                  ok
Checking database connection settings                       ok
Checking for prepared transactions                          ok
Checking for reg* system OID user data types                ok
Checking for contrib/isn with bigint-passing mismatch       ok
Checking for roles starting with 'pg_'                      ok
Checking for invalid "line" user columns                    ok
Checking for presence of required libraries                 ok
Checking database user is the install user                  ok
Checking for prepared transactions                          ok

*Clusters are compatible*
```

Ok everything positive, here we go, lets try upgrading.

First, ran as root, as described [here](https://medium.com/@plashchynski/postgresql-upgrade-on-centos-4c0ddd2f8687):

```
service postgresql stop
```

Then, the upgrade command (as postgres user):

```
/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_upgrade --old-bindir=/usr/bin/ --new-bindir=/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/ --old-datadir=/var/lib/pgsql/data/ --new-datadir=/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/
```

Got the ERROR output inside the */var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_upgrade_server.log* file:

```
271 -----------------------------------------------------------------
272   pg_upgrade run on Fri Mar  2 15:44:09 2018
273 -----------------------------------------------------------------
274
275 command: "/usr/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/var/lib/pgsql/data/" -o "-p 50432 -b  -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700 -c unix_s    ocket_directory='/var/lib/pgsql/data'" start >> "pg_upgrade_server.log" 2>&1
276 waiting for server to start....FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "unix_socket_directory"
277  stopped waiting
278 pg_ctl: could not start server
279 Examine the log output.
```

How to get this done?

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You must have copied `postgresql.conf` from the 92. cluster to the 9.6 cluster.
That won't work, because some parameters have changed.

For example, `unix_socket_directory` from 9.2 became `unix_socket_directories` in 9.3; now you can have more than one of them.

You should use the default 9.6 `postgresql.conf` and edit it manually to match your 9.2 configuration. Some parameters have changed quite radically, like `checkpoint_segments`, which has been replaced by `max_wal_size`.